# Docker can't connect containers

Tags: docker

So I want to run a redis container and a jupyter container that makes requests to the redis server and plots that data. I run

```
sudo docker run --name=redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
sudo docker run -d --name=jupyter -p 8888:8888 hantaowang/visualizer start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

But the notebook will not run. It says `ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.` Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I use my own dockerfile instead.

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
ADD visualizer.ipynb visualizer.ipynb
RUN pip3 install redis
```

Comment: You should clarify which approach you are using as the solution will be different. Generally, you would want to run your application in a different container from your data service. Seems like a good use case for Docker Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 1):

You need link the redis container to jupyter container with option `--link`.

Go through the README of official `redis` container.

https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

You should be fine to link it with below sample:

```
$ docker run --name some-app --link some-redis:redis -d application-that-uses-redis
```

So your command should be changed to

```
# No need expose the port 6379 now, because you link redis container to the other directly
$ sudo docker run --name=redis -d redis

$ sudo docker run -d --name=jupyter --link redis:redis -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: So you need to update your question with the real command you run and provide us the new error message.

Comment: The command I provide is the actual, word for word, command that I am running. And the error message is the actual message provided by Jupyter upon trying to connect to redis.

Comment: Frist I fixed the image name, you missed a `r` in it.

Comment: Second, I paste the command you should run as, will this work?

Comment: Let me try it out thanks. Does it matter that I actually use my own dockerfile. I've updated the post.

Comment: And no it somehow doesn't work. Ive already tried this before. I have another container that also uses the redis server and I was able to connect by setting --net=host on that container. HoweverI can not do that with jupyter.

Comment: Are you sure? If you have another container, you need link redis containter as well

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` always points to the "computer" (virtual or otherwise) that made the request. In this case `127.0.0.1:6379` points to the jupyter container that is making the request.

use `resis:6379`

when you name a container, docker adds that name to the private docker network

Comment: where do I add that do? `sudo docker run --name=redis:6379 -p 6379:6379 -d redis` like this?

Comment: You need to use an IP address from where the Docker host is running. You can run a command like `ifconfig` from the host computer and then verify it's accessible from the container your service is running. Or use docker-compose and link them, or some other network share. See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ and/or https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/